# Does logarithmic differentiation not work for all problems or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate the function:

$$f(x)=(5x^2-8x)e^x$$

I know applying basic product rule first gives me a right answer.

$$f'(x)=(10x-8)e^x+(5x^2-8x)e^x=e^x(5x^2+2x-8)$$

However, I initially tried using logarithmic differentiation in which my answer came out different.

$$f(x)=(5x^2-8x)e^x$$

$$\ln(y)=\ln((5x^2-8x)e^x)$$

expand using properties of $ln$
$$(\ln(y)=\ln(5x^2-8x)+\ln(e^x)) d/dx$$

implicit differentation
$$\frac{y’}{y}=\frac{1}{5x^2-8x}(10x-8)+1$$

subsitute $y$ from $f(x)$
$$y'=(5x^2-8x)e^x\frac{1}{5x^2-8x}(10x-8)+1$$

cancel out $(5x^2-8x)$
$$y'=e^x(10x-8)+1$$

simplify; *wrong*
$$f'(x)=e^x(10x-7)$$

I am genuinely curious, does logarithmic differentiation not work here, or did I mess up along the way; can you please explain?

Comment: On the line $y'=(5x^2-8x)e^x(1/(5x^2-8x))(10x-8)+1$, you have to distribute the $y = (5x^2-8x)e^x$ to the $+1$ too.

Comment: @peterwhy Wow, I did it over twice, and still didn't catch that. THANK YOU

Comment: Apart from that, simplify $e^x(10x-8)+1$ to $e^x(10x-7)$ is wrong; $e^x(10x-7) = e^x(10x-8)+e^x$.

Comment: The key fact is that $A(B+C)$ is different from $AB + C$. Make sure you have parentheses where they are needed and don't imagine them where they shouldn't be. Also, $(\ln(y)=\ln(5x^2-8x)+\ln(e^x)) d/dx$ is just bizarre; I would write $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(5x^2-8x)+\ln(e^x)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting formatting to view stacked fractions really helped.

The problem in my logarithmic differentiation was where the $y$ was distributed. It should be corrected to:

$y'=(5x^2-8x)(1/(5x^2-8x))(10x-8)+1$

$y'=\frac{e^x(5x^2-8x)}{5x^2-8x}(10x-8)+(5x^2-8x)$

$y'=(5x^2+2x-8)e^x$

Thank you all for your help @peterwhy @intellect4

Comment: @Leucippus: Huh?  The question ends with: "I am genuinely curious, does logarithmic differentiation not work here, or did I mess up along the way; can you please explain?"  This answer shows how Manny "mess[ed] up along the way", and so is an answer.